# {"Error":"Lambda.SdkClientException","Cause":"Unable to execute HTTP request: Request did not complete before the request timeout configuration."}}

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem with running step functions locally using npm run start. When I run a state machine called WaitMachine , it is stacked on the first state which triggers a lamda function called hello, it prints hello and stacked at the same state !. Could you please help me ? and Thanks .

```
I got this error: {"Type":"ExecutionFailed","PreviousEventId":5,"ExecutionFailedEventDetails":{"Error":"Lambda.SdkClientException","Cause":"Unable to execute HTTP request: Request did not complete before the request timeout configuration."}}
```

My serverless yml is :

```
service: stepfunctions

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions-local
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-offline-lambda
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  serverless-offline:
  stepFunctionsLocal:
    accountId: 101010101010
    region: us-east-1
    TaskResourceMapping:
      FirstState: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:101010101010:function:hello
      FinalState: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:101010101010:function:world

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello 
  world:
    handler: handler.world
  startSF:
    handler: handler.startSF
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: GET

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    WaitMachine:
      definition:
        Comment: "An example of the Amazon States Language using wait states"
        StartAt: FirstState
        States:
          FirstState:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 
              Fn::GetAtt: [hello, Arn]
            Next: FinalState
          FinalState:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 
              Fn::GetAtt: [world, Arn]
            End: true
```

My handler.js is :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
module.exports.startSF = (event, context, callback) => {
  const stepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({ endpoint: 'http://localhost:8083' })
  const stateMachineArn = process.env.OFFLINE_STEP_FUNCTIONS_ARN_WaitMachine
  const params = {
    stateMachineArn
  }

  return stepFunctions.startExecution(params).promise().then(() => {
    callback(null, `Your state machine ${stateMachineArn} executed successfully `)
  }).catch(error => {
    callback(error.message);
  })
}

module.exports.hello = async event => {
  console.log('hello')
  return { foo: 1 }
}

module.exports.there = async event => {
  console.log('there')
  return { message: 'Final thing!!!', event }
}

module.exports.world = async event => {
  console.log('world')
  return { message: 'Final thing!!!', event }
}

My package.json is :

{
  "name": "stepfunction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "delete": "aws stepfunctions --endpoint-url http://localhost:8083 delete-state-machine --state-machine-arn 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:101010101010:stateMachine:WaitMachine' &",
    "start": " serverless offline start --stage local-dev"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^8.0.0",
    "serverless-offline-lambda": "^1.0.6",
    "serverless-step-functions-local": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1446.0",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```